# How is console.developers.google.com different from appengine.google.com?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Google Cloud has https://console.developers.google.com/ and App Engine has http://appengine.google.com.  Are they interchangeable?  Will http://appengine.google.com eventually become obsolete in favor of https://console.developers.google.com/?  If I start using https://console.developers.google.com/ will I be unable to go back to http://appengine.google.com?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jordan Fish from Google Cloud Platform Support gave me this answer:

> https://console.developers.google.com is the next generation portal for managing all Google Cloud Platform projects.  Currently you can manage many, but not all aspects of your AppEngine app from within the Developer's Console and there are some places where it will redirect back to the AppEngine admin console.  You can use both without any ill-effect, just know that at some point (I am unsure of the timeframe) the admin console (appengine.google.com) will cease to exist.

Comment: I believe that's the trend as well, an obvious sign is for new app engine apps, the billing is enabled via the new console, and also they are adding new functions to the new console such as error log, performance graphs etc. But until today, there are many things only available from the original admin console (e.g. budget control)

Answer (score 0):

As we get closer to fully migrating the App Engine Admin Console to the Google Cloud Platform Console and the launch of a bigger and better Identity and Access Management (IAM) system, there is an upcoming change to the existing Admin Logs.

The Permissions page in the Cloud Platform Console allows an owner to add users to or remove users from a project, along with changing a role.  All of these actions are logged and can be viewed today within the Admin Logs of the Admin Console.  Later this week, these entries will stop showing up within the Admin Console.

Instead, these entries will be available within the Cloud Platform Console, under the Activity page in the Home section.  Look for events titled ‘Set IAM policy’ and expand these events for all the details.