# How is it different between Console.Cloud and Console.Developer

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-developers-console

I think it's not a good questions, but I have been instructed to use Console.Cloud to create a Service Accounts to access Google Sheet from Python3. Now, I'm trying to use Resumable Upload to upload large Video to Google Drive. I have done some research and found that I need to create an OAuth 2.0 under Console.Developers.

I'm not too sure what is the different between those 2 platforms, even though they are showing the same credentials that I have created.

Comment: Cloud Console is the integrated Google Cloud Platform management console[1]
the link[2] provides you insight about google developer console[2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/cloud-console

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302453/how-is-console-developers-google-com-different-from-appengine-google-com

Answer (score 1):

Those two platforms are different ways to visualize Google resources. The Developers console lets you view your app's credentials with Google, while the Cloud Console allows for visibility into Google Cloud resources as well as into the API credentials shown on the Developers console. I believe that now you can only see your credentials through the APIs & Services section of the Cloud console, since that is what I see when I type https://console.developers.google.com.

For more detail into the many consoles provided by Google and the different type of resources in Google's ecosystem, checkout [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62858975/how-is-console-developers-google-com-different-from-console-cloud-google-com) Stackoverflow thread.